# Adding Row Using PHP/JavaScript/AJAX to Database

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, sql-insert

I have a button that can be clicked that will bring up a popup box with one textfield. Whenever, I enter something and click "Add", I want it to be inserted into my database.

Currently, when I click "Add", it will insert into the DB, but it will not read the value that was entered. Therefore, a null value is simply entered. I get no errors that I can see, however in my JavaScript I do a `console.log(type + " : " + value);` and it returns `sku_group-0 :` in the logs. I also do a `console.log(dict)` and the output in the log is `Object {}` so it doesn't look like the entered value is being logged. I also am getting a successful `row inserted` message in the logs too so it definitely looks like it is just a matter of being able to get the values to be read so they can then be processed in the `insert-group.php` script.

So my question is how can I get it to read the value in the JavaScript so that it can be successfully entered into the database?

HTML of Popup Box:

```
<div id="dialog-form" title="Add Group">
  <p class="validateTips">Please Add a Group</p>

<!-- Dialog box displayed after add row button is clicked -->
  <form>
    <fieldset>        

      <label for="sku_group">SKU Group</label>
      <input type="text" name="group" id="group" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">


      <!-- Allow form submission with keyboard without duplicating the dialog button -->
      <input type="submit" id="submit" tabindex="-1" style="position:absolute; top:-1000px">
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
```

HTML of Add button:

```
<button class="create-user" id="insertButton">Add Group</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
$( function() {   

    var dialog, form,

      sku_group = $( "#group" ),
      allFields = $( [] ).add( sku_group ),
      tips = $( ".validateTips" );
  console.log(allFields);

    function updateTips( t ) {
      tips
        .text( t )
        .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" );
      setTimeout(function() {
        tips.removeClass( "ui-state-highlight", 1500 );
      }, 500 );
    }

    function checkRegexp( o, regexp, n ) {
      if ( !( regexp.test( o.val() ) ) ) {
        o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
        updateTips( n );
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }


   function addGroup() {

      var valid = true;
      allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
// ----- Validation for each input in add row dialog box -----
      valid = valid && checkRegexp( sku_group, /^[a-z]([0-9a-z_\s])+$/i, "Please enter a valid SKU Group name" );
      console.log(allFields);
      if ( valid ) {
        var $tr = $( "#skuTable tbody tr td" ).eq(0).clone();
        var dict = {};
        var errors = "";
        $tr.each(function(){
        var type = $(this).attr('id');
        var value = $(this).html();
        console.log(type + " : " + value);

      switch (type) {
        case "group":
            dict["SKU Group"] = value;
        break;
        }
    });
        $( "#skuTable tbody" ).append($tr);
        dialog.dialog( "close" );
        console.log(dict);


        var request = $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "insert-group.php",
          data: dict
        });

        request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR){
          if(JSON.parse(response) == true){
            console.log("row inserted");
          } else {
            console.log("row failed to insert");
            console.log(response);
          }
        });

        // Callback handler that will be called on failure
        request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
            console.error(
                "The following error occurred: "+
                textStatus, errorThrown
            );
        });

        // Callback handler that will be called regardless
        // if the request failed or succeeded
        request.always(function () {

        });

}

      return valid;
    }

    var dialog = $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      height: 400,
      width: 350,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Add Group": addGroup,
        Cancel: function() {
          dialog.dialog( "close" );
        }
      },
      close: function() {
        form[ 0 ].reset();
      }
    });

    form = dialog.find( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
      event.preventDefault();
      addGroup();
    });

    $( ".create-user" ).button().on( "click", function() {
      dialog.dialog({
          show: 'blind',
          hide: 'blind'
      });
      dialog.dialog("open");
    });

  });
```

insert-group.php script:

```
<?php

  $SKU_Group = $_POST['SKU Group'];

  $host="xxxxxxxxxxx"; 
  $dbName="xxxxxxx"; 
  $dbUser="xxxx"; 
  $dbPass="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

  $pdo = new PDO("sqlsrv:server=".$host.";Database=".$dbName, $dbUser, $dbPass);

  $sql = "INSERT INTO SKU_Group_Dim ([SKU Group]) VALUES (?)";

  $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
  $result = $stmt->execute(array($SKU_Group));
  echo json_encode($result);

?>
```

Comment: try using return false; instead of event.preventDefault(); - sounds like your form post is happening.

Comment: @Paul I get the same outputs in my log when using `return false;`

Comment: Have you tried instead of just loggin dict   , logging dict["SKU Group"] . Seems its displaying that is an object, so it finding it.  Also i cannot see on the php function that you are assigning dict to anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    REPLACE 
    "data: dict" 
    WITH 
    data:{ 'SKU_Group' : $('#group').val() } 

    AND 

    REPLACE 
    "$SKU_Group = $_POST['SKU Group'];" 
    WITH 
    $SKU_Group = $_POST['SKU_Group'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should get your input value with:

```
$('#group').val()
```